# Matching python statement/expression boundaries when searching in pycharm

Tags: regex, pycharm

A common thing I want to do, when doing a search-replace in an IDE (in this case: PyCharm), is to avoid cutting expressions or statements in half.

For example, suppose I want to fix the fact that my is using python-2-style print statements. I might write:

Search: `print (.+)`, replace: `print($1)`

But this will do the wrong thing for multi-line statements:

```
print 'one' \
      'two'
```

In general, recognizing multi-line statements is complicated. You need to check for trailing \s and also do bracket-matching for multiple types of brackets. Is there built-in functionality for doing this? Some kind of end-of-statement / end-of-expression escape sequence?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it this way.

Find `print((?:.+?(?:\\\r?\n)?)+)`
Replace `print($1)`

Expanded

```
 print 
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           .+? 
           (?: \\ \r? \n )?              # Possible line-continuation
      )+
 )                             # (1 end)
```